# How do I create buttons on a custom list form?

Tags: list, list-form, custom, item

I have custom list(on SharePoint 2007). The user receives an email with link to this list. In each row(item) the user needs to fill-in data.

**I want to create two types of buttons:**

1. When the user finishes filling in data in the **specific(one) item** he will press on the button in order to complete that step, and that press will transfer the user to the next item.
2. When the user finishes filling in data in the **entire list(all the items)** he will press on the button, and that press will return the user to the home page.

How can I create these buttons?

Comment: You have a great question here, but I made some slight improvements based on [our  guidelines](http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/115/have-any-tips-for-editing-questions/116#116). You can also read [How to Ask](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) for more general guidelines. Also, for #1, is the button redirecting the user to the next item? What action does the button do?

Comment: thank you for your response. the button propose is to redirect the user to the next item. and color the item row in diffrance color. is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Create custom edit forms for the list.  You can either create a custom list edit form in SharePoint Designer or in InfoPath.  When you create the link in your email, amend the source attribute to point back to your home page.

WSS 3.0 / MOSS

http://kalsing.blogspot.com/2006/11/create-custom-list-form-for-sharepoint.html

Foundation / SP 2010

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/edit-list-forms-using-infopath-2010-in-sharepoint-designer-HA101631624.aspx

Comment: Those links are for creating custom forms for a list, not creating a list.  Once you have a custom form, you can add the buttons.  You can use the button controls from SPDesigner or InfoPath, or you could create HTML buttons that calls JavaScript, etc.

Comment: SharePoint Designer is a tool for customizing SharePoint, available free from MS download site.  It is a very powerful tool at that.  Since you are unfamiliar with it, I suggest you spend a good deal of time getting acquainted with it and working on a test platform before touching anything in production.  Take a look at this series here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/demos-a-six-part-series-on-getting-the-most-out-of-sharepoint-designer-2007-HA010219984.aspx.

Comment: You may want to pick up a good book and keep it handy.  MS Step by step series is pretty easy to get around:  http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0735625336/ref=pd_lpo_k2_dp_sr_1?pf_rd_p=486539851&pf_rd_s=lpo-top-stripe-1&pf_rd_t=201&pf_rd_i=B000HCXKKI&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_r=0S197HNM9SCZVFTQHZBM

Comment: thanks! I will cheack the book and I might purchase it. until then do you know some way to create a button without using SP forms?

Comment: See this: http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2008/11/sharepoint-color-coding-sharepoint.html and this http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2008/09/01/using-calculated-columns-to-write-html/  Hope that helps.

Comment: hi Jesus!this article that you gave me is wonderful techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2008/11/… thank you!!!!!!

Comment: do you know how to add button in the "list toolbar"? near to the New/ Action/ Setting. E.G: I have invite your recommended book :)

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing sounds like a workflow. Each item completed allows the user to complete the next item. 
Instead of doing that, which could get messy if you have several workflows, try this.

Investigate the survey list.

Answer (score 0):

look at this link:

http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:Rc5hv7sLoL8J:sharepoint.microsoft.com/Blogs/GetThePoint/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx%3FID%3D136+create+button+sharepoint&cd=1&hl=iw&ct=clnk&gl=il&source=www.google.co.il

this post explain how to create button on sharepoint with the "content editor web-part" without using sharepoint design :)

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

**Create button on sharepoint list:**

http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:Rc5hv7sLoL8J:sharepoint.microsoft.com/Blogs/GetThePoint/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx%3FID%3D136+create+button+sharepoint&cd=1&hl=iw&ct=clnk&gl=il&source=www.google.co.il

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

One way of achieving this is to create a webpart which uses SP.ListOperation.Selection. getSelectedItems(context) and use the values to operate on. Your webpart will also contain the required buttons, just like regular aspx (button_OnClick)

Then attach this webpart into AllItems.aspx (or any other view page) of the custom list. The getSelectedItems() will return the items selected in that list.